# Update query in Python using Dictionary key Value pairs

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, dictionary, cx-oracle

Im in my beginning days of learning python, my requirement is based on a column in Oracle Table im updating other column using dictionary key pair Values. My Dictionary looks like this

{'United States': 'American', 'France': 'European', 'Great Britain': 'European'}

So when Country column is United States the description column should be updated to American, after my database connection, here is my code

```
query = "select country from details_table "
        cursor.execute(query)
        returnrows = cursor.fetchone()
        while returnrows is not None:
                pickedvalue=returnrows[0]

               mainvalue=file_dictionary[pickedvalue]


                updatequery = "update details_table set description='%s' where country='%s'"

                cursor.execute(updatequery %(mainvalue,pickedvalue))
                returnrows = cursor.fetchone()
```

When i execute this im getting Error "Not a query", so i tried changing the quotations im getting different Error each time

```
updatequery = "update details_table set description=%s where country=%s"
updatequery = "update details_table set description='%s' where country=%s"
```

for above two queries i got ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

```
updatequery = "update details_table set description=%s where country='%s'"
```

for this i got ORA-00904: "AMERICAN": invalid identifier

Can someone tell me which would be the correct query for this to work, i even tried like below with no luck

```
updatequery="update details_table set description={} where country='{}'"
sql=updatequery.format(main_value,pickedvalue)
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not attempt to use string interpolation to update your query! Instead, please use bind variables as noted in the [documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html).

Your example would look something like this:

```
query = "select country from details_table"
cursor.execute(query)
returnrows = cursor.fetchall()
for rows in returnrows:
    for pickedvalue in rows:
        requiredvalue = file_dictionary[pickedvalue]

        print(requiredvalue)
        updatequery = "update details_table set description=:1 where country=:2"
        cursor.execute(updatequery, [requiredvalue, pickedvalue])

        connection.commit()
```

Another way to do this with cursor iteration and tuple unpacking is as follows:

```
query = "select country from details_table"
cursor.execute(query)
updateCursor = connection.cursor()
for country, in cursor:
    requiredvalue = file_dictionary[country]

    print(requiredvalue)
    updatequery = "update details_table set description=:1 where country=:2"
    updateCursor.execute(updatequery, [requiredvalue, pickedvalue])

    connection.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you Anthony, it is working good, can you also help me what is the issue with my while loop and fetchone() i have used (mentioned in question )

Comment: You're welcome. I don't see another question? Can you clarify?

Comment: I just want to get this done using fetchone() and while loop

Comment: What i understood here is it doesnt allow to  use fetchone() in while loop as fetchone method requires select query before it, if we define select query again after the update query here it again loops to first record...but i want to know if we can do it by any chance..

Comment: I added another approach -- using cursor iteration. You can use cursor.fetchone() as well, but cursor iteration is more convenient! Note that if you are iterating over a cursor you will need to use a different cursor for performing the update.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what is the magic, it started working with this, i cant understand what is the logic difference between this and above code, someone please let me know

```
 query = "select country from details_table"
        cursor.execute(query)
        returnrows = cursor.fetchall()
        for rows in returnrows:
            for pickedvalue in rows:
                requiredvalue = file_dictionary[pickedvalue]

                print(requiredvalue)
                updatequery = "update details_table set description='%s' where country='%s'"
                cursor.execute(updatequery % (requiredvalue, pickedvalue))

        connection.commit()
```